# How to change a text with a button in a dynamically generated list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, playframework

I use the play framework 2.3.8 and I'm trying to change a certain text value next to a button. The button gets dynamically added via a generated list, so I am not able to find the correct text that is next to the button.

This is what it looks like:
[image: Example]

My view class gets a list of questions `questionList: List[Question]` over which I iterate and put a bunch of buttons into my html:

```
@for(question <- questionList){
<!-- Questions -->
<li class="list-group-item" >
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  id="upvoteButton" 
value="voteUp" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" style="color:orange"></span>
</button>

<span class="num"> @question.voteScore </span>

(...)
```

In the class "num" is the actual voteScore for the question which I want to change on a button click. The id-tag is not helping, as the buttons get generated and therefore all have the same id-tag (Sidenote: Only the first id actually works, I guess the first button gets the unique id?).

My approach so far:

If I click on the `num` itself I can change it's value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.num', function(){
                $(this).html(111);
                });
        });
```

But trying to accomplish this with a button click fails:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-default").click(function(){
        $(this).slideUp().slideDown();
        console.log($('.num').html());
    });
});
```

The output of console.log always is 76, no matter which button I click. I am not able to find the button that is linked to the correct num. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
$(".btn-default").click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp().slideDown();
    $(this).next('.num').html('111');
});
```

or also you can try:-

```
 $(".btn-default").click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp().slideDown();
    $(this).parent('li').find('.num').html('111');
});
```

Comment: Just noticed: Inside of the for-loop I have another for-loop for the answer-buttons (from an answerList). The script does only work for the question-buttons on the outside-loop as I dont know how to address the inner buttons. Any ideas?

Comment: The solution to the nested problem is to use the immediate child selector: `$(this).parent('li').find('> .num')`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your buttons are not 'visible' while you are doing document.ready init call so I would suggest to add it this way,, to be live or bound to dom after dinamic call ends..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on( 'click', '.btn-default' , function(){
        $(this).slideUp().slideDown();
        console.log($('.num').html());
    });
});
```

hth, k